# Swipe Right to Dismiss ViewControlelr without using Storyboard Swift

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, gestures

How to dismiss any View Controller without using Storyboard ? and do I have to use UINavigationController to achieve this ? if not how then ?

Comment: Have you tried using a UISwipeGestureRecognizer? When you set it up, you can do something like
`let swipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismiss))
            
swipeGesture.direction = .right
`

Comment: There is nothing like dismissing any view controller. The way of taking the VC offscreen is bounded to container view controller you use. Dismissing is for modal presentations, popping is for navigation controllers etc. Everything depends on your layout.

Comment: @spenseram  i actually ended up using uinavigation controller , without storyboard of course

Comment: @KamilSzostakowski i haved tried thst before its not dragging then it ugly i used uinav and its okey now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to dismiss a view controller is to call a dismiss method on the presenting view controller. If you presented your child controller from a parent by calling `self.present(_:animated:)` then you can call `self.dismiss(animated:)`. If you used a navigationController and called `navigationController.push(_:animated:)` then you need to tell the navigation controller to dismiss with `navigationController.popViewController(animated:)`
Method names might not be exact, but you should be able to figure it our with autocomplete.

Comment: thanks I have used this way and its handleing the the drag but is the view really gone when its popped or its not just visible ?

Comment: Glad to hear this is working for you! When you pop a view controller it's really gone. Unless you have a retain cycle. You can analyze your app in xcode using the visual memory debugger and searching for your view controller's class name.

Comment: yeat but when i pop a view controller and push another I still can swipe back to previous one , i don't wanna disable this swipe feature but mu point is the vc is not actually gone

Comment: ok i think there is a miscommunication... when you have 3 controllers like so: VC1, VC2, VC3 then you have your window root controller is VC1.


1) Push/Present VC2 means that VC1 and VC2 are in memory
2) Pop/Dismiss VC2 means you are back to VC1 and it's the only one in memory
3) Push/Present VC3 means that VC1 and VC3 are in memory


So when you said "really gone when it's popped", i thought you were referring to a VC that had been pushed then popped like in example 2.

Answer (score 1):

if someone is still struggling to dissmiss on swipe (left,right,bottom,top)
i came across a very elegant and decent cocapod [panslip](https://github.com/k-lpmg/PanSlip)

with a very simple usage

just call this method in viewDidLoad()

For viewController embedded in navigation Controller

```
let viewControllerVC = self.navigationController

    viewControllerVC!.ps.enable(slipDirection: .leftToRight){
        
        //anything you want to do after dissming
        
    }
```

For Simple View Controller

```
let viewControllerVC = self

    viewControllerVC!.ps.enable(slipDirection: .leftToRight){
        
        //anything you want to do after dissming
        
    }
```

For TableView embedded in View Controller

```
let viewControllerVC = self.YourTableview.parentContainerViewController()

    viewControllerVC!.ps.enable(slipDirection: .leftToRight){
        
        //anything you want to do after dissminn
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to swipe right is not a dismiss, but I think that what you want it to embed the `UIViewController` inside a `UINavigationController`.

For example:

```
if let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryboard", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourViewController") as? YourViewController {
  let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
  navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```